# Why myList(i) does not pass througp property Item in BindingList(of T) inherited class

Tags: .net, bindinglist

I have create a class that inherits from `BindingList(of T)` and I added a property 
`Item(indx as Integer)` that shadows base property item as it follows

```
<System.Reflection.DefaultMember("Item")> _
Public Class Unity(Of T As {New, Entity})
    Inherits BindingList(Of T)
    Implements IUnity

    Public Property Item(ByVal indx As Integer) As T
        Get
            If indx >= Me.Count Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index")
            End If
            If Not MyBase.Item(indx)._IsLoaded Then InitDataOfItemsInPage(indx)
            Return MyBase.Item(indx)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As T)
            MyBase.Item(indx) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ......
End Class
```

Now when i try to acces an item writing `myUnity.Item(1)` everythings works fine.
The code goes to the property Item does what it has to do and returns the myEntity.
But if I write `myUnity(1)` I get myEntity without passing through the property item
Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "default property item" from BindingList(of T) takes precedence before DefaultMemberAttribute in Unity(...) class. I don't know why.

`Default Property Item(ByVal indx As Integer) As T`
instead of 
`<DefaultMember>(...)`
works fine.